# Split a hex file to another files according to a condition

Tags: java, io, hex

I have a hex file have values like

> f0 01 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 3d 61 c1 c1 df 40 02 00 c0 00 00 09 18 16 00 ef 01 40 00 00 3f 20 f0 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 c7 a2 c1 c1 df 40 02 00 c0 01 00 09 18 16 00 ef 01 40 00 00 3f 20 f0 01 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 e4 c1 c1 df 40 02 00 c0 02 00 09 79 09 04 c7 01 e1 4e 02 3f 00 f0 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 d9 25 c2 c1 df 40 02 00 c0 03 00 09 02 19 25 3c 00 22 6a 01 db 09 f0 04 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 62 67 c2 c1 df 40 02 00 c0 04 00 09 02 19 25 3c 00 22 6a 01 db 09 f0 01 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 ec a8 c2 c1 df 40 02 00 c0 05 00 13 7b 06 04 a4 0d 91 0c b6 c4 4e 02 3f 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 01 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 6b 13 c3 c1 df 40 02 00 c0 06 00 13 7b 2b 04 93 0d 43 13 b6 c4 2e 00 3f 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 01 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 e9 7d c3 c1 df 40 02 00 c0 07 00 13 7b 4f 04 d6 0d 2e fc b5 c4 2e 00 3f 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 01 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 68 e8 c3 c1 df 40 02 00 c0 08 00 13 7b 55 04 ca 0d 7b 10 b6 c4 29 00 3f 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 01 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 e7 52 c4 c1 df 40 02 00 c0 09 00 13 7b 46 04 f1 0d c5 15 b6 c4 2e 00 3f 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00

I want whenever I find `f0` followed by `01` followed by `01` to copy these pattern and whatever after it till the next `f0` and so on till I have all the patterns that have these sequence 
and save it in a file

and whenever I find `f0` followed by `01` followed by `02` to copy these pattern and whatever after it till the next `f0` and so on till I have all the patterns that have these sequence 
and save it in another file

and so on with `f0` `01` `03` till `f0` `01` `09`

Here is what I tried to do

```
String filename = "C:\\tm09888.123";
FileInputStream in = null;
int readHexFile = 0; 
char hexToChar = ' ';
String[] bytes = new String[10];

try
{            
    in = new FileInputStream(filename); 

    while((readHexFile = in.read()) != -1)
    {       
        if (Integer.toHexString(readHexFile).equals("f0"))
        {
            System.out.print("\n\n\n");
        }
        System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(readHexFile) + " ");
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Logger.getLogger(NARSSTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

}

I split all the pattern from `f0` but how could I tell the program to look after `f0` to be followed by `01` `01`

and then save all these patterns in another file

Comment: You need to create a recursive descent parser: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: Can the patterns you describe be nested, one inside the other?  A state machine will do if they can't be nested.  Some manner of stack-based parser will be needed if they can be nested.

Comment: There is no such thing as a hex file. You have a *file,* and you have *printed* a hex *representation* of it. @WillC.: There is no need for a parser, recursive descent or otherwise: this problem can be handled by a regular expression.

Comment: @EJP You could certainly use a regular expression to solve this problem, but that does not disqualify creating a simple recursive descent parser.